# How to display a flag to anonymous users?

Tags: 7, flags, users

I'm using the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, but I have a problem in displaying a flag to anonymous users.

I have 2 flags called "make feature" and "add to Favorites". I want to display this flag to anonymous users too. Currently it is displayed only to the users who are logged in (authenticated user).

I want these flags to be displayed to all users (whether logged in or not). But when an anonymous user clicks on flag than such user should be redirected to the login page. After login the user should be able to set flag.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's a flag in your context? A menu entry?

Comment: @BetaRide : I think OP is talking about flags by [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module

Comment: yes i am using flag module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this in your 'node.tpl.php' by something like below, if user is logged in display flag as normal and if is not logged in redirect user to logging page with `destination` parameter

```
global $user;
if(!$user->uid) {
    // $flag: bookmark or make_feature, $action: flag, $content_id: $nid.....
    $flag_link = flag_flag_link($flag, $action, $content_id);
    $flag_url = $flag_link['href'];
    if(isset($flag_link['query']['token'])) {
        $flag_url .= '?'.$flag_link['query']['token'];
    }
    print l(t('bookmark'), 'user/login' , array('query'=> array('destination' => $flag_url)));
} else {
    print render($content['links']['flag']);
}
```

Comment: Thanx its working.

Answer (score 4):

To **display a flag to anonymous users**, refer to what's written in the community documentation of the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module, i.e.:

> Flagging for anonymous users (even with page caching enabled). Requires [Session API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_api).

Something similar from the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/flag/tree/README.txt#n63):

> Optional Installation
>
> 1) The ability for anonymous users to flag content is provided by the Session API module, available at http://drupal.org/project/session_api.

Be aware also that [Session API](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_api) isn't mentioned as a [dependency in the Flag module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/flag/tree/flag.info) either.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_anon

> Offer an option to display of "sign in or register" for a flag for
>   anonymous users.