# How to display flags to anonymous users and redirect to login after clicking a flag?

Tags: flags

I want to display flag to anonymous user and upon clicking the user should be redirected to register/login page.

I found one answer to this problem in the question about 
"[How to display a flag to anonymous users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35472/display-flag-to-anonymous-user/42159#42159)".

I tried this solution but did not work, may be I did not put the code in correct place?

I am using Bartik as my template and I put the code in `node.tpl.php`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i put it just at the end of the file, not under any specific function.

Comment: Under which function i am supposed to put this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display flag to anonymous user](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35472/display-flag-to-anonymous-user)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Flag anonymous](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_anon) module is what are you looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the [Session API](http://drupal.org/project/session_api) module.

> The Session API is a very simple set of functions that extend the core
>   sessions workings, allowing data to be stored and associated with a
>   user's session.
>
> There is no need to install this module unless you are instructed to
>   do so by another module.
>
> Currently this module is used by
>
> Flag DrupalChat Mozilla Persona Session Favorites Domain User Default
>   The Sign-Up Problem

Comment: Because the session API module is essentially abandoned (last release was in 2012, and is not stable - see RC1 in the name.)  It currently breaks the page cache, and if you are using a reverse-proxy cache it will not work.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/1983696