# bookmark organize for anonymous user permission

Tags: flags

I have use drupal 7. I download and install the flag , flag bookmark, bookmark module.I have also add settings for bookmark. Bookmark functionality is work for authenticated and admin user. i wanna functionality for anonymous user. So how can I use for anonymous user ?

I have check the permission but they can't provide the permission for anonymous user.

so can you explain me how can I do this task ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the features of the flag module are designed to be used by authenticated user only, so not by anonymous users.

The closest you can come to address your question, is as is described in [How to display a flag to anonymous users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35472), i.e.:

> When an anonymous user clicks on flag, then such user should be redirected to the login page. After login the user should be able to set flag.

And then do as described in the answer to that same question, i.e.:

> You can do this in your 'node.tpl.php' ...: if user is logged in then display flag as normal; if not logged in then redirect user to logging page with destination parameter.